# How to conditionally display a form based on a users' radio button selection?

Tags: html, forms, asp-classic, vbscript

I am trying to create a list of radio buttons that when the user selects one option a different form is displayed than if they select another radio button. For example, if they select "Add category" the associated form will display but if they select "delete category", a form allowing them to delete the category would display.

At the moment I am using a variable called "stage" and moving through the process by setting stage to different numeric values as they are passed through the hidden data of each form. Unfortunately I cannot get it to display anything other than the form in stage 2.

```vbs
<% option explicit %>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!--#include file="dbconn.asp"-->
<!--#include file="header.asp"-->

    <div class="content">

<div class="content-inner container_12">

  <div class="wrapper prefix_2 grid_8 suffix_2">
<%

  dim stage, SQL, info 
  stage = request.form("stage")
  if stage = "" then stage=1

  '------------------------------------------------------------------
  if stage = 1 then
  '------------------------------------------------------------------

'                     0     1       
         SQL="select ID, category "&_
             "from categorytable "&_
             "order by category DESC"

        set info=conn.execute(SQL) 

        if info.eof then

          response.write "<p>There are no categories</p>"

        end if

    '--- create a radio-button list of the current posts
    response.write "<form id=""categoryedit""action=""category.asp"" method=""post"">" &_
                   "<input type=""hidden"" name=""stage"" value =""2"">"&_
                   "<label for=""addcategory"">Add Category</label>"&_
                   "<input id=""addcategory"" type=""radio"" name=""addcategory"" value=""stage = 2""><br>" &_
                   "<label for=""deletecategory"">Delete Category</label>"&_
                   "<input id=""deletecategory"" type=""radio"" name=""deletecategory"" value="" stage = 4""><br>" &_
                   "<label for=""editcategory"">Edit Category</label>"&_
                   "<input id=""editcategory"" type=""radio"" name=""editcategory"" value="" stage = 6""><br>" &_
                   "<input class=""button"" type=""submit"" value=""Select"">" &_
                   "</form>" 

  '------------------------------------------------------------------
  elseif stage = 2 then
  '------------------------------------------------------------------

  response.write "<form action=""category.asp"" method=""post"">" &_
                   "<input type=""hidden"" name=""stage"" value =""3"">"&_
                   "<label for ""category"">New Category</label>"&_
                   "<input type=""text"" id=""category"" name=""newcategory"" required><br>"&_
                   "<input class=""button"" type=""submit"" value=""Add Category"">"&_
                   "</form>"



    '------------------------------------------------------------------
  elseif stage = 3 then
  '------------------------------------------------------------------

     dim category 
      category = request.Form("newcategory")

  sql = "insert into categorytable (category) "&_
        "values ('" & category & "')"
        conn.execute sql

      response.write "<p>New Category added.</p>"


  '------------------------------------------------------------------
  elseif stage = 4 then
  '------------------------------------------------------------------
   '              0     1       
         SQL="select ID, category "&_
             "from categorytable "&_
             "order by category DESC"

        set info=conn.execute(SQL) 


  response.write   "<form action=""category.asp"" method=""post"">" &_
                   "<input type=""hidden"" name=""stage"" value =""5"">"&_
                   "<label for ""category"">Delete Category</label>"
                   do
    response.write "<label for=""radio""></label>"&_
                   "<input id=""radio"" type=""radio"" name=""categorytobedeleted"" value=""" &_
                    info(0) & """>" &_
                    info(1) & "<br>"

   info.movenext
    loop until info.eof
    response.write  "<input class=""button"" type=""submit"" value=""Delete Category"">"&_
                   "</form>"

   '------------------------------------------------------------------
  elseif stage = 5 then
  '------------------------------------------------------------------

  dim deleteCategory
  deleteCategory = Request.Form("categorytobedeleted")
  sql = "delete * from categorytable where ID= "& deleteCategory 
conn.execute(sql)
  response.write  "<p>Category deleted.</p>" 

'------------------------------------------------------------------
  elseif stage = 6 then
  '------------------------------------------------------------------
 '              0     1       
         SQL="select ID, category "&_
             "from categorytable "&_
             "order by category DESC"

        set info=conn.execute(SQL) 


  response.write   "<form action=""category.asp"" method=""post"">" &_
                   "<input type=""hidden"" name=""stage"" value =""7"">"&_
                   "<label for ""category"">Edit Category</label>"
                   do
    response.write "<label for=""radio""></label>"&_
                   "<input id=""radio"" type=""radio"" name=""categorytobeedited"" value=""" &_
                    info(0) & """>" &_
                    info(1) & "<br>"

   info.movenext
    loop until info.eof
    response.write  "<input class=""button"" type=""submit"" value=""Edit Category"">"&_
                   "</form>"

  '------------------------------------------------------------------
  elseif stage = 7 then
  '------------------------------------------------------------------
  dim record_num
  record_num=Request.Form("categorytobeedited")
  if record_num="" then response.redirect "?pg=category"

    '                 0             1                                             
  SQL=  "SELECT categorytable.ID, category "&_
        " FROM CategoryTable"&_
        " WHERE categorytable.ID= "&record_num

  set info=conn.execute(SQL)
%>
        <form action="category.asp" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="stage" value="8">
        <input type="hidden" name="categorytable.ID" value="<% =record_num %>">
        <label for="category">Category</label>
        <input id="category" type="text" name="title" value="<% =info(1) %>"><br>
        <input id="edit" class="button" type="submit" value="Edit">
        </form>

<%

 '------------------------------------------------------------------
  elseif stage = 8 then
  '------------------------------------------------------------------

  dim addcategory
  addcategory = request.form("categorytable.ID")

  sql="update categorytable set category='"& addcategory & "'" &_
      "where categorytable.ID= "& addcategory

      conn.execute sql

       response.write "<p>Category edited.</p>"


  '------------------------------------------------------------------
  end if  ' stage
  '------------------------------------------------------------------

  if stage = 8  then
    response.write "<a href=""category.asp"">Show Categories</a>"

    end if
  conn.close 
%>

  </div>

</div>

</div>


<!--#include file="footer.asp"-->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This section looks wrong. A group radio buttons should share the same variable name. Change the name of your radio buttons so they are ALL named "stage". Remove the hidden field with the name "stage" and set the values of the radio buttons to just numeric values.

```
response.write "<form id=""categoryedit""action=""category.asp"" method=""post"">" &_
               "<input type=""hidden"" name=""stage"" value =""2"">"&_
               "<label for=""addcategory"">Add Category</label>"&_
               "<input id=""addcategory"" type=""radio"" name=""addcategory"" value=""stage = 2""><br>" &_
               "<label for=""deletecategory"">Delete Category</label>"&_
               "<input id=""deletecategory"" type=""radio"" name=""deletecategory"" value="" stage = 4""><br>" &_
               "<label for=""editcategory"">Edit Category</label>"&_
               "<input id=""editcategory"" type=""radio"" name=""editcategory"" value="" stage = 6""><br>" &_
               "<input class=""button"" type=""submit"" value=""Select"">" &_
               "</form>"
```

Correct code should look something like this

```
  <form id="categoryedit" action="category.asp" method="post">
      <label for="addcategory">Add Category</label>
      <input id="addcategory" type="radio" name="stage" value="2"><br>
      <label for="deletecategory">Delete Category</label>
      <input id="deletecategory" type="radio" name="stage" value="4"><br>
      <label for="editcategory">Edit Category</label>
      <input id="editcategory" type="radio" name="stage" value="6"><br>
      <input class="button" type="submit" value="Select">
  </form>
```